# Rewrite rules - multiple requests priorities

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to make some sense with a multi-page and multi-domain redirect .htaccess and can't find a solution. Of course my bad...

For SEO optimization I need to redirect all the old subdomains pages of a project to the main domain root BUT some pages, that should be redirected to a chosen main domain  subdirectories.

Example:

```
old.domain.com/         => www.domain.com/
old.domain.com/subdir   => www.domain.com/

old.domain.com/specific => www.domain.com/newspecific
old.domain.com/another  => www.domain.com/newanother
```

I'm not really good at rewriting rules and I came up with something like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
# should be old.domain.com/specific => www.domain.com/newspecific
RewriteRule https://2014.designintown.org/2014/07/30/progetto-food-design/  https://www.designintown.org/progetto/ [R=301,L]

# should be old.domain.com/ => www.domain.com/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.designintown.org/ [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

While the second rule seems to work, the first doesn't.
What am I getting wrong?
Thank you in advance for your support.

UPDATE

I eventually solved it with:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/2014/07/30/progetto-food-design/$
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.designintown.org/progetto/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/borse-di-studio/$
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.designintown.org/agevolazioni/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/docenti/$
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.designintown.org/docenti/ [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.designintown.org/ [R=301,L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: `RewriteRule` matches against the _path_ component of the URL only - so the pattern you tried to use there in your first rule, will of course never match. If you want to check the host name of the request, you need to do that by preceding the rule with a RewriteCond.

Comment: Does the main domain point to a different server? "redirected to a chosen main domain subdirectories" - Are these actual subdirectories (ie. physical directories on the filesystem?) or just "virtual" URL-paths. If they are "subdirectories" then they need to end with a trailing slash. And to clarify, you are only redirecting specific pages, not all URLs with a specific prefix?

Comment: I eventually solved it. See Updated Post.

Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

I eventually solved it with:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/2014/07/30/progetto-food-design/$
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.designintown.org/progetto/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/borse-di-studio/$
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.designintown.org/agevolazioni/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/docenti/$
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.designintown.org/docenti/ [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.designintown.org/ [R=301,L]

</IfModule>
```